# Storing and Displaying TextArea user inputs

Tags: c#, html, string

How can i handle user inputs with textarea, i need to strip user entered html tags, store text somewhere and display it back in a webpage. 
I also need to take care about line breaks

Any best practices without using `<pre>` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do a find-replace of `\n` with `<br />` to preserve line breaks.

However, stripping html is a bit trickier. The easiest thing to do is replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. But that doesn't actually strip the html, it merely forces it to render as plain text instead of html.

You could use a regex replace to remove `<anything>` but that has many potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using PHP, you can always use the nl2br() function to display the text back on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function called SafeComment designed to eliminate the problem characters from the input for SQL, javascript, HTML and VB. Since our sites and code are almost all VB & VB script. It's function is to allow any freeform input field to be successfully received, processed, saved and displayed. We needed it to maintain PCI compliance.
It's not pretty, but it works.

```
Function SafeComment(ByVal strInput)
' Renders Any Comment Codes Harmless And Leaves Them HTML readable In An eMail Or Web Page
' Try: SafeComment("`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}][|\'"";:<>?/.,")
    SafeComment = ""
    If Len(strInput) = 0 Then Exit Function
    SafeComment =   Replace( _
                    Replace(Replace(Replace( _
                    Replace(Replace(Replace( _
                    Replace(Replace(Replace( _
                    Replace(Replace(Replace( _
                    Server.HtmlEncode(Trim(strInput)), _
                    ":", "&#58;"), "-", "&#45;"), "|", "&#124;"), _
                    "`", "&#96;"), "(", "&#40;"), ")", "&#41;"), _
                    "%", "&#37;"), "^", "&#94;"), """", "&#34;"), _
                    "/", "&#47;"), "*", "&#42;"), "\", "&#92;"), _
                    "'", "&#39;")
End Function
```